# hi.how to deploy Asp.net website in IIS6.0 in windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net

i trying to deploy my Asp.Net website in IIS6.0 in windows server2003 64 bit.but when i try to browse the my site it showing page cant be displayed. 
More I unable to ASP.Net Tab in my website Propeties.

Could you Please guide me how to deploy the my application inn IIS6.0 and windows server 2003 64 bit..

Thanking you,
sant

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Web Sites and Virtual Directories for your applications, have a look at [this Technet guide](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/2f45f2ea-bcf8-4d23-9f15-5caf7ebdc2ef.mspx) for more information.

Comment: yes i created all reguler frmalities like iis5.1 an win Xp but i could n't browse my application,, Even in propertied i unable see ASp.net Tab in IIS. for you information already i register Aspnet in IIS like Aspnet_regiis -i i tryied all ways ..please try help me i hanged here